# matching an encryption method in NodeJS compatible with the decryption one

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I have a method in NodeJS that decrypt a payload coming form a C# request and it is working fine.

```
function _decryptMessage(_encryptedData, _encryptedDek, _iv, _privateKey, _kek){

    const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt({
      key: _privateKey,
      passphrase: _kek,
      padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
    }, Buffer.from(_encryptedDek, "base64"));

    const dek = decrypted.toString("utf16le");
    const buff = Buffer.from(_encryptedData, "base64");
    const key = Buffer.from(dek, "utf8");
    const iv = Buffer.from(_iv, "utf8");
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);

    return decipher.update(buff).toString() + decipher.final().toString();
 }
```

For unit testing reason, I would like to write a NodeJS equivalent method that encrypts a json payload that can be decrypted by the above function.
I am trying to revert the code but something is missing because I am getting a **error:0200009F:rsa routines::pkcs decoding error**

This is the unfinshed method I cannot complete:

```
function _encrypt(_publicKey, _data){

    const dek = "bf3c199c2470cb477d907b1e0917c17b";
    const iv = "5183666c72eec9e4";

    const encryptedData= (() => {

      const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", dek, iv);
      let encryptedData = cipher.update(_data, 'utf8', 'base64');
      encryptedData += cipher.final('base64');

      return {
        encryptedData
      };

    })();

    const encryptedDek = crypto.publicEncrypt({
      key: _publicKey,
      oaepHash: "sha1",
      padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
    }, dek).toString("base64");
    return {
      encryptedDek,
      iv,
      encryptedData
    };

 }
```

I would need help to complete the encrypt method that can use the above decrypt as it is.

Comment: I think you should use `return Buffer.concat([decipher.update(buff), decipher.final()]).toString()` instead of trying to decode the buffers separately

Comment: @Bergi - This is an alternative, but what the OP does also works. The `update()` calls always return only that part of the Base64 string that is not changed by subsequent `update()`/`final()` calls. The padding is only generated by the `final()` call.

Comment: @Topaco Not sure what you mean by padding, there should be no padding in the decoded data? I don't worry about how the decryption consumes the buffer, I worry about `update` returning a buffer that cannot be decoded as a UTF8 string.

Comment: @Bergi - Sorry, I had mistakenly referred your comment to the encryption. Right, this should be fixed in the decryption (via concatenation as you suggested, or by directly decrypting `_encryptedData` and specifying the input/output encoding). According to the OP, decryption works, so maybe they haven't noticed this yet, perhaps because the plaintext consists mainly of single-byte UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `_encrypt()` function:

- the AES key for the RSA encryption must be encoded with UTF-16LE
- PKCS#1 v1.5 must be applied (and not OAEP)
- the `encryptedData` must be returned as string (and not as object)

```js
function _encrypt(_publicKey, _data){

    const dek = "bf3c199c2470cb477d907b1e0917c17b";
    const iv = "5183666c72eec9e4";

    const encryptedData= (() => {
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", dek, iv);
        let encryptedData = cipher.update(_data, 'utf8', 'base64');
        encryptedData += cipher.final('base64');
        return encryptedData; // Fix 3
    })();

    const encryptedDek = crypto.publicEncrypt({
        key: _publicKey,
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING // Fix 2
    }, Buffer.from(dek, 'utf16le')).toString("base64"); // Fix 1
    
    return {
        encryptedDek,
        iv,
        encryptedData
    };
}
```

With this change, a ciphertext generated with `_encrypt()` can be decrypted with `_decryptMessage()`.

---

Note that the derivation of key and IV from a string using UTF-8 encoding is a vulnerability that is forced on the encryption method by the design of the decryption method.

In addition, the key and IV are usually not hardcoded, but randomly generated for each encryption (but probably the hardcoded values are due to your test case).